# order vyatta failed via api. error id 236

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We sent an API call to order Vyatta in account 910593. This API worked well before but failed this time. We got this error message:

> "The price 20000 GB Bandwidth (33867) is not valid for package
>   (236)."

Below is our request body:

```
 {"orderContainers"=>[{"quantity"=>2,
 "hardware"=>[{"hostname"=>"sjc01-ded-910593-A",
 "domain"=>"bluemix.softlayer.com",
 "primaryBackendNetworkComponent"=>{"networkVlanId"=>1178249}},
 {"hostname"=>"sjc01-ded-910593-B", "domain"=>"bluemix.softlayer.com",
 "primaryBackendNetworkComponent"=>{"networkVlanId"=>1178249}}],
 "location"=>168642, "packageId"=>236, "prices"=>[{"id"=>49347},
 {"id"=>22527}, {"id"=>36043}, {"id"=>32927}, {"id"=>33990},
 {"id"=>33867}, {"id"=>24713}, {"id"=>33644}, {"id"=>34241},
 {"id"=>34996}, {"id"=>33483}, {"id"=>35310}, {"id"=>34807},
 {"id"=>32500}, {"id"=>32082}, {"id"=>25014}]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the valid item prices for package `“236”`, the price `“33867”` is not available for this package. The request used to confirm it is:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/236/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[id,locationGroupId,item[id,keyName,description],pricingLocationGroup[locations[id, name, longName]]]

Method: GET
```

The unique Bandwidth price available for this package is: `31241`

```
{
"id": 31241
"locationGroupId": null
"item": {
"description": "0 GB Bandwidth"
"id": 439
"keyName": "BANDWIDTH_0_GB_2"
}-
}
```

Below is a REST example that works successfully using the above price:

URL:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
```

Method: POST

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "orderContainers": [
        {
          "hardware": [
            {
              "hostname": "vyattagw",
              "domain": "mydoamin.com"
            }
          ],
          "location": 168642,
          "packageId": 236,
          "quantity": 1,
          "prices": [
            {
              "id": 49347
            },
            {
              "id": 22527
            },
            {
              "id": 36043
            },
            {
              "id": 32927
            },
            {
              "id": 33990
            },
            {
              "id": 31241
            },
            {
              "id": 24713
            },
            {
              "id": 33644
            },
            {
              "id": 34241
            },
            {
              "id": 34996
            },
            {
              "id": 33483
            },
            {
              "id": 35310
            },
            {
              "id": 34807
            },
            {
              "id": 32500
            },
            {
              "id": 32082
            },
            {
              "id": 25014
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**References:**

[Get valid item Prices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices)